# Why are those weird results calculating years between two JODA instants?

Tags: java, jodatime

Recently I stumbled over the hint to use Years.between() as JODA best practice to calculate someones age. It does not work in general as the following example demonstrates.

```
    DateTime y0000 = new DateTime(0000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime y2000 = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    assertEquals(2000, new Period(y0000, y2000).getYears());
    assertEquals(1999, Years.yearsBetween(y0000.toInstant(), y2000.toInstant()).getYears());
    assertEquals(1999, new Period(y0000.toInstant(), y2000.toInstant()).getYears());
    assertEquals(2000, new Period(new DateTime(y0000),new DateTime(y2000)).getYears());
```

Does JODA work here as designed or is this a JODA defect?

UPDATE:
JODA works as designed. If you really want to use `Years.between()` then either work with `LocalDateTime` or make sure to work with `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

Comment: The result of 1999 for instant-conversion can probably be explained by the fact that timezone data are not well defined in far past. Joda-Time uses estimated zone offsets with second parts. This can result in different offsets for year 0 and year 2000 and hence decremented year delta. It is also important to understand that the timezone idea is an idea of the 19th century! So your code is meaningless ;-) The dark side by design here is also that Joda-Time enables code without making the timezone effect visible and explicit.

Comment: It is not only for the "far past". I also discovered the same problem with [1940,2000]  being 59 years according to JODA. All other intervals (1940,2000] are correct.

Comment: This can also be explained by different timezone offsets for 1940 and now. It depends on your system timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From my comment (now transferred into this answer):*

The result of 1999 for instant-conversion can be explained by the fact that timezone data are not well defined in far past. Joda-Time uses estimated zone offsets with second parts (so called LMT entries in the TZDB-database). This can result in different offsets for year 0 and year 2000 and hence decremented year delta. It is also important to understand that the timezone idea is an idea of the 19th century! So your code is meaningless ;-) The dark side by design here is also that Joda-Time enables code without making the timezone effect visible and explicit.

**I have now investigated the offsets in my local timezone using this code:**

```
System.out.println(DateTimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(y0000.toInstant()) / 1000); // 3208 s
System.out.println(DateTimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(y2000.toInstant()) / 1000); // 3600 s
```

The consequence is: You have to subtract the first smaller offset from y0000 and to subtract the bigger offset from y2000 so the delta in seconds between both instants cannot be equal to 2000 years expressed in seconds. Therefore the year delta is decremented.

In order to avoid such unexpected deltas (where you do obviously not think about any timezone effects) I strongly recommend to use types like `LocalDateTime`. This type has no timezone in contrast to `DateTime` and will do what you expect (of course without conversion to `Instant`). Otherwise, if you care about "exact" physical time differences (either by different summer/winter-time or historical estimation of offsets) then the expected year difference is not really correct i.e. should take into account the timezone offsets.

Comment: Working with LocalDateTime works indeed. The class name is confusingly named as "Local" indicated my local time (with timezone).

Comment: It is also possible to work with `DateTime` if time zone `UTC` is used, i.e.  DateTime y0000 = new DateTime(0000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,DateTimeZone.UTC);`

Comment: "Local" essentially means "Timezoneless" in Joda (and JSR310) type names

Comment: @whaefelinger I agree that the name `LocalDateTime` is confusing but it is now set in stone. Many people new to this API stumble about the name. Of course, we can get accustomed after some time ;-)